# jQuery on() not working on element inside disabled fieldset

Tags: jquery, click, dynamically-generated, fieldset

```
<form>
  <fieldset disabled='disabled'>
    <input type='text' name='text' value='not to be edited' />
    <a href='#' class='editbutton'>click me</a>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

jQuery not working:

```
$("body").on("click", ".editbutton", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("hello");
});
```

jQuery working:

```
$(".editbutton").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("hello");
});
```

So, when you take $("body") as a starting point, jQuery does not catch the event click on the editbutton, because of fieldset being disabled.

If you take $(".editbutton") as a starting point, jQuery works, although fieldset is still disabled.

Is this expected behaviour and is there a workaround? I cannot use the working solution because the form is created dynamically.

Comment: Please create a fiddle in your question where we can reproduce your problem. Your posted code totally works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code totally works, so there must be additional JS that screws up your logic.

```js
$('.js-button').on('click', function() {
  $('.js-copy').eq(0).clone().appendTo('body');
});


$("body").on("click", ".editbutton", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("hello");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="js-button"> copy form </button>
<form class="js-copy">
  <fieldset disabled='disabled'>
    <input type='text' name='text' value='not to be edited' />
    <a href='#' class='editbutton'>click me</a>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: No, there is no other JS screwing up, I tried a plain setup with above code only. I have noticed that it also does not work on a static form, so I've edited my question. Because my form is dynamically created, I cannot use the working example.